# Table chart using nvd3

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I have created bar chart, pie chart and stacked area graph using nvd3. But now I want to create table chart using same data. Is there any way to create table chart using json data in nvd3 ?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?

Comment: Yes.. for nvd3 .. But can't find table chart

Comment: I don't know nvd3, but perhaps that's because you can't make a "table chart" with it

Answer (score 0):

Let's turn his question into: how do you extend nvd3 to create new chart types?  I could not find documentation on this.

I'd personally like to combine the candlestickBarChart with a lineChart.